# How to add element to existing list without creating new variable in erlang?

Tags: list, foreach, erlang, append

I have a list contains some elements and now with the help of `lists:foreach` I am fetching some more records and I want to append each value to my existing list elements without creating new variable as doing in other languages with help of array.

Here is my sample code which I am getting:

```
exception error: no match of right hand side value [6,7,1].
```

Sample Code:

```
listappend() ->
    A = [1,2,3,4,5],
    B = [6,7],
    lists:foreach(fun (ListA) ->
        B = lists:append(B, [ListA])                       
        end, A),
    B.
```

I want output like,

```
B = [6,7,1,2,3,4,5].
```

Comment: Actually I want to make dynamic like, I dont know how many elements are there in list A. and how many new variables I will create and how do I know that in loop how many variables created and what is my last variable that I have to show? Please help...

Comment: You can't add to an existing list. Immutability prevents this. [Read here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#invariable-variables)

Comment: Thanks Gert...But is there any other way to achieve this...

Comment: Ajay, you need to use a different variable: B1 = B ++ A.  There is no way to re-bind B to a different value once it's already bound to the list [6,7].

Comment: lists:foreach/2 is really not used for list manipulation.  It's for side-effect producing functions such as I/O or message passing.  List manipulation should be side-effect free.  The lists module provides other functions for side-effect free list manipulation such as append/2, map/2 and foldl/3, and many others.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, this feature already exists, so you won't need to implement it yourself. In fact, the list can take two lists as arguments:

```
1> lists:append([1,2,3,4,5], [6,7]).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Which is actually implemented as:

```
2> [1,2,3,4,5] ++ [6,7]. 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Please bear in mind that the ++ operator will copy the left operand, so this operation can easily lead to quadratic complexity. Said that, you probably want to construct your lists using the "cons" operator (eventually reversing the list at the end of the computation):

```
3> [1|[2,3,4,5,6,7]].
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

In any case, you can have two arguments in your function, which are the two lists to append, instead of defining them in the body of the function. This way, the values of A and B will change every time you call the `my_append/2` function.

```
my_append(A, B) ->
  YOUR_CODE_GOES_HERE
```

As a note and regarding the actual error you're getting, this is due to the following line:

```
B = lists:append(B, [ListA])
```

During each iteration, you're binding a new value to the variable `B`, which is already bound to the value `[6,7]`.

Comment: Yes Roberto, I got it but my requirement is like that only, I want to make dynamic like, I dont know how many elements are there in list A. and based on loop how many new variables I will create and what is my last variable that I have to show? This is the actual issue which I am facing. Please help...

Comment: I want the above output in B only...How it is possible in Erlang

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Erlang are immutable. That means you cannot assign a new value to a variable once it has been bound, and this is why you get the 'no match' error. The old value does simply not match the new value you are trying to assign to the variable. Instead, you can create a new list using e.g lists:append based on the old one. You should probably start by looking at recursion and how you can use it to manipulate lists.